# WMP 12.0 adds duplicate entries for same file mapped network drive

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, deduplication

Windows Media Player 12 is adding duplicate entries for each file on my mapped network drive. When I try and rebuild the index by going to %UserProfile%\Appdata\Local\Microsoft\Windows Media, I am unable to find any index files (or any files)  There is in that directory another folder labeled 12.0 that includes two files "WMSDKNS.XML and WMSDKNS.DTD" THe XML file is just a list of accepted protocols

How do I fix the duplicates?  (The duplicates are not pointing to two different files, but are indeed duplicates for the same file..)

Answer (score 0):

The following steps can be used to reset WMP's media library. Note that resetting the library will make you lose all current play counts, and possibly ratings too.

- Reboot the PC.
- Go to Start, type **services.msc** in the Search field, and press Enter. In Services, find the **Windows Media Player Network Sharing Service**. If its status is **Started**, double-click the service and click **Stop**.
- Go to Start, type **%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft** in the Search field, and press Enter. This folder will open up in Windows Explorer.
- In this folder, delete the **Media Player** folder. If you can't see the folder, then it's probably hidden. Set Explorer to show hidden files and folders, and to show protected system files.
- Start WMP, your library will have been reset and will be rebuilt.

Comment: I tried that on Windows 7 (actually I renamed the folder instead of deleted it).  DLNA didn't work anymore (no library offered from that machine, it would appear Windows made no attempt to rebuild the library).  lucky I had just renamed...

Comment: Rebuilding the library should start as soon as WMP is started again. To make DLNA work again, you should restart the `Windows Media Player Network Sharing Service`.

Comment: it would seem the thing to do is simply empty out the folder and restart WMP.  confirmed that works.  

thank you for your contribution!

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/windows-media-player-media-library-is-corrupted/1dd3982a-7122-4bc9-b667-79b60c237734?auth=1